# Could not search array value

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to search value of order using `array_search` function i have tried following ways but it does not work.

printed array display output

```
PostDaataArray
(
    [order_id] => 5464
)

$currentKey=array_search($orderId,$postedData);
```

also tried `$currentKey=array_search($orderId,array_column($postedData, 'order_id'));`

But when i tried to search array using array_search function it does not work also not showing error as well.

Comment: show us the value of `$postedData['order_id']`?

Comment: I changed  $postedData is an array

Comment: look i have print postdata at top in my question.

Comment: What error it is showing?

Comment: Nothing error is showing , error log is already on but there is no error display , execution stop after array_search function.

Comment: PostDaata change name to PostData then it'll work

Comment: how you converted $posteddata into array.

Comment: `array_search` would return `order_id` in this case.

Comment: When i print  $postedData['order_id']; then it's display order id value but when i used it in array_search not work

Comment: if you found orderid in array what you expected to return and store in currentkey

Comment: ` $postedData['order_id'] = 5464;
 print_r($postedData);
 $orderId = 5464;
 $currentKey=array_search($orderId,$postedData);
 print_r($currentKey);` this code returns order_id

Comment: I found order_id in array but currently order_id value is 5464 but after found order_id using array_search then try to get array using order_id it's display only 5 instead of 5464.

Comment: check you data array is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

If previously data in JSON format then decode it:

```
$postedData = json_decode($postedData,true);
```

You can use in_array():

```
if(in_array($orderId,array_column($postedData, 'order_id'))) //check value is in array
{
   $key = array_search($orderId,array_column($postedData, 'order_id')); //return index or key of array
}
else
{
  //order id not in array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$PostDaataArray=array("order_id"=>"5464");
foreach($PostDaataArray as $key=>$order_id){
    if($order_id=="5464"){
        // match found.
    }
}
```